# How do I set min and max for bottom axis for candlestick series in TeeChart?

Tags: java, android, teechart

I'm trying to display a candlestick series with TeeChart library.

Everyting is fine except I can't control the range of data displayed. The question is when I add new data to my series, I want to scroll my bottom axis to display the last *N* values. E.g. when I add a new candle, I want to scrol +1 index to display this bar.

I found that Axis class has 2 methods for doing this:

```
axis.setMinMax(DateTime arg0, DateTime arg1)
axis.setMinMax(double arg0, double arg1)
```

Which is the right method to use in conjunction with Candles? I guess that this is the 1st overload that takes 2 DateTime params, but I'm adding values to the Candle series without a specific date:

```
Candle series = ...
...
series.add(bar.getOpen(), bar.getHigh(), bar.getLow(), bar.getClose());
```

so all of the points have a default date.

Also I tried to use `axis.setMinMax(double arg0, double arg1)` specifying *startIndex* and *endIndex* I wanted to display, but it doesn't seem to be working...

Is it possible to control range in my case with candles without specifying a DateTime value for each series' value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the *startIndex* and *endIndex*, you could do this:

```
axis.setMinMax(series.getXValues().getValue(startIndex), series.getXValues().getValue(endIndex));
```

Another alternative, if you know the offset to apply to the axis, would be calling the axis scroll method, ie:

```
int myOffset = 1;
axis.scroll(myOffset, true);
```

And another alternative, if you know the number of values to display:

```
int nValuesToShow = 10;
axis.setMinMax(series.getXValues().getValue(series.getCount()-nValuesToShow-1), series.getXValues().getValue(series.getCount()-1);
```

Finally note the `Add()` override without date (without XValue) is adding your value with getCount() as XValue.