# Place Candles on Chart Without Overlapping

Tags: java, android, teechart

I'm using a TeeChart library to display Candlesticks chart on Android.

Just for now I'm developing a simple SWT application to test some capabilities of the library.

I'm adding about 400 candles to my chart using

`series.add(c.getOpen(), c.getHigh(), c.getLow(), c.getClose())`

By the time when there're a lot of candles displayed they begin ovelap with each other.

What is the best way to avoid this?
My idea was to calculate the number of candles which can be displayed without overlapping using chart width, candle width and some spacing between candles:

```
private int getNumberOfCandlesVisible() {
    final Candle candles = (Candle) series;
    final int panelWidth = chart.getWidth();
    final int candleWidth = candles.getCandleWidth();

    return panelWidth / (candleWidth + CANDLE_SPACING);
}
```

Then I tried to display last N values if `series.getCount > getNumberOfCandlesVisible()` using zoom or `setMinMax()` an axis. Is it the right way? 
I want to scroll the chart to display to most actual values as they apper, but it doesn't seem to be smooth... Maybe there's an option somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350626/how-do-i-set-min-and-max-for-bottom-axis-for-candlestick-series-in-teechart/25365503#25365503), isn't it?
Then, I guess the major issue here is how to smooth the transition.
To do this you could use a TimerTask in Android. Ie:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Timer timer;
    MyTimerTask myTimerTask;
    int cycleCount;

    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    cycleCount++;

                    if (cycleCount <= 60) {
                        double tmpIncr = (tChart1.getSeries(0).getXValues().getLast() - tChart1.getSeries(0).getXValues().getValue(tChart1.getSeries(0).getCount()-2)) / 60;
                        tChart1.getAxes().getBottom().setAutomaticMaximum(false);
                        tChart1.getAxes().getBottom().setMaximum(tChart1.getAxes().getBottom().getMaximum()+tmpIncr);
                        tChart1.refreshControl();
                    } else {
                        startStopTimer(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout group = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_layout1);
        createChart(group);
        initializeChart();
    }

    private TChart tChart1;
    private int timerInterval, testIndex;
    private int chartPaintCtr;
    private int pointsRefreshed, pointsPlotted;
    private float myDensity;

    private void createChart(LinearLayout group) {
        tChart1 = new TChart(this);
        group.addView(tChart1);
    }

    private void initializeChart() {
        // apply theme
        ThemesList.applyTheme(tChart1.getChart(), 1);
        // multitouch drag zoom
        tChart1.getZoom().setZoomStyle(ZoomStyle.INCHART_MULTI);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        myDensity = metrics.density;
        tChart1.getAspect().setFontZoom(
                tChart1.getAspect().getFontZoom() * myDensity);

        // hide things for better speed
        tChart1.getAspect().setView3D(false);
        tChart1.getLegend().setVisible(false);
        tChart1.getFooter().setVisible(false);
        tChart1.getHeader().setVisible(false);
        tChart1.getWalls().setVisible(false);

        tChart1.getZoom().setAnimated(true);
        tChart1.getZoom().setAnimatedSteps(15);

        FastLine lineSeries1 = new FastLine(tChart1.getChart());
        lineSeries1.fillSampleValues();

        tChart1.getAxes().getTop().getGrid().setVisible(false);
        tChart1.getAxes().getRight().getGrid().setVisible(false);

        int sep = 150;
        tChart1.getAxes().getTop().getLabels().setSeparation(sep);
        tChart1.getAxes().getRight().getLabels().setSeparation(sep);
        tChart1.getAxes().getBottom().getLabels().setSeparation(sep);
        tChart1.getAxes().getLeft().getLabels().setSeparation(sep);

        tChart1.getPanel().setMarginLeft(7);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tChart1.getZoom().setAnimated(false);
                msgSet = false;

                chartPaintCtr = 0;
                cycleCount = 0;

                Random generator = new Random();
                int tmpRandom = generator.nextInt((int)tChart1.getSeries(0).getYValues().getRange()/10);

                tChart1.setAutoRepaint(false);
                tChart1.getSeries(0).add(50, tChart1.getSeries(0).getYValues().getLast()-(int)tChart1.getSeries(0).getYValues().getRange()/20+tmpRandom);
                tChart1.setAutoRepaint(true);

                startStopTimer(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void startStopTimer(Boolean run) {

        if (run) {

            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
            // re-schedule timer here
            // otherwise, IllegalStateException of
            // "TimerTask is scheduled already"
            // will be thrown
            timer = new Timer();
            myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();

            // delay to first xxms, repeat in xxms
            timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 0, timerInterval);
        } else {
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, we have a FastLine series populated with 25 values. Then, when we press the button, we add another point at a far position (50).